# Add a specific character between the first and second character of a numeric cell

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have an excel sheet with several cells that I'd like to add a "," between the first and second algarythms. For example:

Cell content: 1765

What I need: 1,765

All these cells are on the same column (G), and it goes from G2 to G485.

I know that maybe it's a difficult task, but I'd like to automate it, since there is too many cells, and changing them one by one is impractical.

I tried creating a Macro, but it changed only the cells I've changed while creating the macro.

Comment: can you explain what the `,` means to you?  is it the decimal separator?  It means something different in different contries

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, it is the decimal separator, but I've already tried to changed it on settings, and it didn't work either. This data is obtained from an equipamnet in my lab, and for some reason, when I change the decimal separator to ",", instead of changing the numbers to 1,765, it does 1765,00

Comment: Then, you should divide it by 1000...

Comment: @FaneDuru It could work, but some cells have a value less than 1000, and in these cells the comma is correctly inserted

Comment: How many digits all the involved numbers have? I mean in which interval, in terms of number of digits...

Comment: @FaneDuru maximum 4 digits and minimum 3 digits

Comment: had a typo in my last comment: `=IF(G2:G485>=10;G2:G485/10^(LEN(INT(G2:G485))-1);G2:G485)`

Comment: `=--REPLACE(A1,2,,",")` maybe?

Comment: How does the data get to Excel? Does your equipamnet generate an `.xlsx` file? or some kind of text file?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it comes from a csv file

Comment: As I have written many times, you need to **IMPORT** (not **open**)  the `.csv` file using either the legacy wizard or Power Query. At **that** time, you will have the opportunity to tell Excel the decimal and thousands separator being used in that particular CSV file. Then it should import the data correctly.  If you merely **open** the file, Excel will make assumptions and alter the data in ways which can be difficult to correct afterwards. Much simpler to do it correctly at the start.

Comment: 1.) Excel (Single cell): `=G2/10^(LEN(G2)-1)`, 2.) Excel (Spill): `=G2:G485/10^(LEN(G2:G485)-1)`, 3.) VBA: `With Range("G2:G485"): .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(.Address & "/10^(LEN(" & .Address & ")-1)"): End If`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all guys. your comments helped me a lot.

I used the following function

```
=IF(G217>1;G217/1000;G217)
```

and applied it for all cells I needed.